# pavucontrol rapidly switching profile in configuration tab

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

Been having audio troubles since reinstalling linux. Installed pipewire and pavucontrol. In pavucontrol I noticed my headphone output in the config tab rapidly switches betweeen "pro audio" , "analog stereo (unplugged)", and "analog stereo" until it finally fails to "off". Sometimes it stays stable for a while, sometimes it goes nuts. Seems to happen more often with multiple audio sources running concurrently or when the volume is particularly high. Using a standard audio jack integral to my cheap case. I'm not a computer guy so I apologize if my explaination is lacking. If anyone could tell me how to lock my pavucontrol settings in place I'm guessing that would at least keep it running. Thanks.

Comment: Why ask here?  You've not mentioned any OS/release details; only mentioning Linux where this isn't a Linux Q&A or support site (SE *Unix & Linux* covers Linux; this is a Ubuntu Q&A site only).  You've not yet mentioned anything on-topic for this site.  You might want to correct your question & add details about why you're asking here.